# App crashes at DidSelectRowAtIndexPath in xcode

Tags: ios, syntax

My app crashes when I click on a record that sets text value in a text label and when the value passed is empty.

```
- (void) tableView: (UITableView *)itemTableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath: (NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    NSDictionary *obj = [self.dataCustomerDetailRows objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    self.textfieldCustomerName.text = [obj objectForKey:@"Name"];
    self.textfieldCustomerPhoneNumber.text = [obj objectForKey:@"Phone"];
    self.textfieldCounty.text = [obj objectForKey:@"Name"];
```

The record that causes the error is one that has no value returned in the "Phone" obj, how can  I code to handle this, e.g., where value is NULL, replace with 0.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7031688/check-if-key-exists-in-nsdictionary-is-null-or-not

Comment: No crash log? It's better offer the crash log either. I think what leads your crash is that the index is beyond the array range.

Comment: Aaron, the possible duplicate has no selected answer, how are we to know what was successful?

Comment: Hi Kjuly, I'm not sure where the crash log is? I don't think it is the index beyond, I think it is because nothing is being returned in the index pair, i.e., key = x but value is nothing, see below in my comment to rocky's answer please

Answer (score 1):

```
NSString *text = [obj objectForKey:@"Property"] == nil ? @"0" : [obj objectForKey:@"Property"];
```

Comment: Hi Rocky, thanks for that, I put that into y code and then stepped through it, is see in the Output screen that '2013-09-14 13:21:52.833 FieldSalesApp[65853:a0b] Phone value is: <null>'