# null check for dictionary object before call to intvalue still leads to intvalue calls on null object

Tags: objective-c, dictionary

I get an array of dictionaries back from reading json off a web server and use the following to make sure I got a particular key in the first dictionary in the array before getting its int value:

```
             if([jsonObject[0] objectForKey:@"votes"]!= nil)
             {
             int votes = [[jsonObject[0] objectForKey:@"votes"] intValue];
             [[UserObject userUnique] updateVotes:votes];
             }
```

However, my app still occasionally crashes saying I have called intValue on Null. I have also tried structuring the control statement as

```
if([jsonObject[0] objectForKey:@"votes"])
```

but this also leads to the same error/app crashing. My syntax seems in line with accepted answers on SO ([Check if key exists in NSDictionary is null or not](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7031688/check-if-key-exists-in-nsdictionary-is-null-or-not)). Any suggestions for what else/how else I should check the existence of key-value pair for applying intvalue?

Thank you for any advice.

Comment: what type of object are you storing in the dictionary for "votes"? NSNumber?

Comment: @Fonix it's an NSString

Comment: Please post the full error message. Does it mention `NSNull`?

Comment: @GuillaumeAlgis I would post the full error but I have not been able to generate it on demand. It does mention NSNull. I am trying Jeffery Thomas's answer below and will update to say whether that worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a difference between `nil` and `null`. `nil` is not an object: it's a special pointer value. `null` (as retuned by `[NSNull null]`) is an object: it's needed because it can be stored in containers like `NSDictionary`.

```
NSString *votesString = [jsonObject[0] objectForKey:@"votes"];
if (votesString != nil && votesString != [NSNull null])
{
    int votes = [votesString intValue];
    [[UserObject userUnique] updateVotes:votes];
}
```

---

***EDIT:*** An answer to @SunnysideProductions question

The post you mentioned recommends a way of turning `null` values into `nil` values by creating a `-safeObjectForKey:` method. You are not using `-safeObjectForKey:`, you are using the default `-objectForKey:` method.

Comment: This makes sense. I will try this out, but it contradicts the SO posting I mentioned.

Comment: @SunnysideProductions no it does not. `nil` is returned by `objectForKey:` when the dictionary has **no** value for the passed key. `[NSNull null]` is an object that can be stored in an `NSDictionary` to represent an empty value for example. In particular, in JSON, getting `nil` would mean the JSON object had no such key, but getting `NSNull` would mean the JSON object had the key, which was associated to a `null` value (eg. `{"myKey": null}`). [See this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5716942/touchjson-dealing-with-nsnull)

Answer (score 0):

Be consecutive in your code. Don't run with methods. It would be better add more null- and type-checks in particular in working with json. Let's do it:

```
if (jsonObject && [jsonObject isKindOfClass:[NSArray class]])
{
  NSArray *jsonArray=(NSArray *)jsonObject;
  if (jsonArray.count>0)
  {
    id firstObject=jsonArray[0];
    if ([firstObject isKindOfClass:[NSDictionary class]])
    {
      NSDictionary *jsonDict=(NSDictionary *)firstObject;
      id votesNumber=jsonDict[@"votes"];
      if (votesNumber && [votesNumber isKindOfClass:[NSNumber class]])
      {
        int votes=[votesNumber intValue];
        [[UserObject userUnique] updateVotes:votes];
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Now the code is more safe. Does it still crash?

Comment: I will try this out and let you know in a few hours. It takes a while sometimes to get it to crash.

Comment: p.s. when you say "don't run with methods" does that mean don't call a method on an object without confirming the object's class? Or do you mean something else?

Answer (score 0):

When you call `objectForKey`in nullable dictionary, app gets crashed so I fixed this from following way.

```
- (instancetype)initWithDictionary:(NSDictionary*)dictionary {
id object = dictionary;

if (dictionary && (object != [NSNull null])) {
    self.name = [dictionary objectForKey:@"name"];
    self.age = [dictionary objectForKey:@"age"];
}
return self;
```

}