# Replace value in NSDictionary

Tags: ios, nsdictionary

I have NSDictionary format like this

```
{
  director = "\U514b\U91cc\U65af\U591a\U798f\U96f7";

  duration = 0;

  ename = "3 Headed Shark Attack";

  id = 538;

  language = "\U82f1\U8a9e";

  nation = "\U7f8e\U570b";

  ranking = "\U672a\U5b9a";

  trailer = "<null>";
}
```

This data get from JSon but the last one was null it cause me can't "writetoFile" be successful is any way to solve it  ??

Comment: What language you are using?

Comment: check this link http://stackoverflow.com/a/26182472/5362916