# Looking for an elgant way to check if a Key exsists in a dictionary

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to check if an NSDictionary or NSMutableDictionary contains a key?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2784648/how-to-check-if-an-nsdictionary-or-nsmutabledictionary-contains-a-key)

I can get the an array of the Keys (strings) from the dictionary then loop through it doing a string compare with the Key i want to check for and see if that dictionary contains the key I seek.

But is there a more elegant want to check if the key exists in the dictionary?

```
        NSArray * keys = [taglistDict allKeys];
        for (NSString *key in keys) 
        {
           // do string compare etc
        }
```

-Code

Comment: 2014 answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/22001925/294884

Answer (score 37, accepted):

An `NSDictionary` cannot contain `nil` values, so you can simply use `[NSDictionary objectForKey:]` which will return `nil` if the key does not exist:

```
BOOL exists = [taglistDict objectForKey:key] != nil;
```

EDIT: As mentioned by @OMGPOP, this also works using Objective-C literals using the following syntax:

```
NSDictionary *dict = @{ @"key1" : @"value1", @"key2" : @"value2" };

if (dict[@"key3"])
    NSLog(@"Exists");
else
    NSLog(@"Does not exist");
```

Prints:

```
Does not exist
```

Comment: what about modern objc? if i use dict[@"key"] it will crash

Comment: this does not work for me . gives error .

Comment: Added information about 'an NSDictionary cannot contain nil values' : if you want a key with 'nothing' as a value, just put the object [NSNULL null].

Answer (score 10):

Trojanfoe is likely better, but you could also do:

```
[[taglistDict allKeys]containsObject:key]
```

Answer (score -2):

Assuming the key is of type `NSString` and `keys` is a dictionary, then you should instead be using something like:

```
if [keys containObject:key] {
 // do something
}
```