# How to check if NSDictionary has key-value pair?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have seen answers aleready posted, they all are talking about...
using `objectForKey` method on `NSDictionary`, which is not proper if we dont know the key's.

Comment: How can you check for a particular key-value pair if you don't know the key you're looking for? How will you know if you found it?

Comment: You need to explain your question in more detail.

Comment: If you want to know, if there is a key you do not know, you can simply use `@voodoo` as key.

Comment: if you allocated NSDictinaory ,and then trying to find if it has added with some object,in this case how can you use "objectForKey"?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to check if an NSDictionary or NSMutableDictionary contains a key?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2784648/how-to-check-if-an-nsdictionary-or-nsmutabledictionary-contains-a-key)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `count` property to test if a `NSDictionary` has any entries.

```
if (aDic.count == 0) {
    // aDic is empty.
} else {
    // aDic has some entries.
}
```

And, you can use the `objectForKey:` method to test if a specific entry exist.

For example, I want to know if a key named "foo" exist in the dictionary:

```
if ([aDic objectForKey:@"foo"] != nil) {
    // aDic has a entry named "foo"
} else {
    // "foo" doesn't exsits
}
```

Also, you can simplify this:

```
if (aDic[@"foo"]) {
    // aDic has a entry named "foo"
} else {
    // "foo" doesn't exsits
}
```

Comment: yaah...i was thinking about it a while about ..if (aDic.count == 0) {}..and it did the trick...Thank you.

Comment: @VinodSupnekar Have I explain it clearly? If so, please accept my answer, it's important to me, thanks.

Comment: @VinodSupnekar Glad to help. I add some comments to help you understand it better.

Answer (score -2):

```
if ([yourDictionary isKindOfClass:[NSDictionary class]])
{
    NSLog(@"%@",yourDictionary)
}
```

Comment: add some explanation on how this works, otherwise it has very little value

Comment: How would checking if `NSDictionary` is of `NSDictionary` class solve anything.