# Check JSON has an object NSArray

Tags: json, nsarray, nsdictionary

I'm having a bit of issue with a JSON service response. The service responds two different ways. i.e. rather then producing an error or a meaningful response it throws a another json format at you. Now most of the time this is okay however, there are times where Objective C just gives up because it hasn't handled the new structure (i.e. I am trying to program it to be handled).

I have a basic JSON call and return (Abstract).

```
NSArray *jsonArray = [[NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData: data options: NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error: &e] mutableCopy];
```

When I call a service that provides detailed information I get the following format (No Error)

```
Printing description of jsonArray:
{
    YBBN =     {
        charts =         (
                        {
                id = "5f0ec74a-6e7c-5484-aef2-5929b85d9739";
                type = General;
            },
```

When I call the same service that doesn't have data it provides the following structure producing a crash.

```
Printing description of jsonArray:
{
    NZAA = 0;
}
```

I simply want to check the returning JSON if the **charts** node exists if it does continue on (these are not the droids your looking for) else throw up an error and handle the exception and stop crashing on the user.

I have tried different techniques but each one seems to either entirely skip the "check" or fails entirely.

I've gone back to the drawing board with this, surely there is a simple way of achieving a simple if statement to check. What am I missing?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay I found the issue with the help of this discussion. 
[How to check if an NSDictionary or NSMutableDictionary contains a key?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2784648/how-to-check-if-an-nsdictionary-or-nsmutabledictionary-contains-a-key)

Not sure how I didn't find that before, never the less I was able to test what it suggested and the results worked.

For completion the following code is what I ended up with, hopefully that might help someone else.

```
NSDictionary *newArray = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:0 error:nil];
                       NSString *_icaoCode = airportICAOCode.text;


                        if ([[newArray allKeys] containsObject:_icaoCode]) {
                            NSLog(@"Contains key");
                        }
```