# Faster way for NSMutableDictionary check

Tags: objective-c, nsmutabledictionary

I'm doing some app optimizations and in big loops the checks on NSMutableDictionary's are fairly taxing:

```
if ([self.variantBufferSequence objectForKey:[variant valueForKey:@"model_no"]] == nil) {
    [self.variantBufferSequence setObject:[NSMutableDictionary new] forKey:[variant valueForKey:@"model_no"]];
}
```

Is there a lighter way to check the existence of the entry (`objectForKey`) in the `if`-statement?

Comment: Did you check if most time is spent in `objectForKey`?

Comment: Why do you think the `objectForKey:` call is expensive rather than the `valueForKey` call (which is generally the slower of the two, and can be extremely slow). What is `variant`? Is this test likely to be true often? What did Instruments say when you profiled this? Optimizing one line of code in isolation is seldom the right approach; what value is changing in the loop? How large is this dictionary?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the last versions of objc and clang, you can check existence of a key in a dictionary with a more compact notation.

This little example works for me:

```
NSMutableDictionary *description = @{@"model_no":@"key1"}.mutableCopy;
NSMutableDictionary *dictionary = @{@"key1":@"value1"}.mutableCopy;

if(dictionary[description[@"model_no"]]){
    NSLog(@"It exists!");
} else {
    NSLog(@"It doesn't exists!");
}
```

Try to replace `key1` with `key2` in `description`.

[Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22001925/1392452)

Comment: In my tests, `objectForKey:` is slightly faster than subscripting (I suspect that `objectForKeyedSubscript:` is implemented as a call to `objectForKey:`). I wouldn't expect it to matter much either way, but is there any reason you believe this approach is faster than the OP's code? (Ignoring the removal of `valueForKey:`, which only works if `variant` is a dictionary.)

Comment: This gave me a very minor speed improvement. `variant` is indeed a mutable dictionary with around 20 small values. I tested it repeatedly with the Time Profiler and got about 5% gain. I hoped for something more spectacular, but not complain :)