# I am using if statement to check key is null or not but I can't understand what went wrong

Tags: objective-c, xcode10

Here I am getting the `Notification` List null and it is causing me an exception. Here is my code:

```
if([[response.data valueForKey:@"NotificationList"] isEqual:@""] || [[response.data valueForKey:@"NotificationList"] isEqual:@"<null>"]) {

  NSLog(@"Data not available.!!!");

}
else
{
  NSLog(@"Data available.!!!");
}
```

Comment: @Pratik Prajapati can u elaborate what went wrong why am i not getting the output

Comment: try to check `response.data valueForKey:@"NotificationList"] != nil` and add your full source code

Comment: @ Pratik Prajapati i tried but not working

Comment: from where you getting `response.data` ?

Comment: this what i am getting in response.data....po response.data
{
    NotificationList = "<null>";
    Status = "Data Not Exists.";
    StatusCode = 2;
}

Comment: @ Pratik Prajapati i get value "null" in NotificationList key and i want to check if the value is null print error msg if it is not null execute the code

Comment: `NotificationList` is `NSNull.null`.

Answer (score 2):

When an object is printed or logged as `"<null>"`, that does **not** mean it's a string object whose contents are `<`, `n`, `u`, `l`, `l`, and `>`. (Well, it doesn't *usually* mean that.)

Rather, `"<null>"` is how the singleton instance of `NSNull` describes itself.

So, the proper test is:

```
id notificationList = [response.data valueForKey:@"NotificationList"];
if (!notificationList || [notificationList isKindOfClass:[NSNull class]])
    NSLog(@"Data not available.!!!");
```

Comment: thank you guys it is working fine..thank you so much @Wileke

Answer (score 0):

You should just be able to check for the key returning a value...

```
if(!response.data[@"NotificationList"]) {

  NSLog(@"Data not available.!!!");

}
else
{
    NSLog(@"Data available.!!!");
}
```

https://stackoverflow.com/a/2784675/285190 - for more details